# RCSwitch activates two times for one touch

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I need to implement custom UISwitch and for this I'm using RCSwitch class (thanks to Ray Wenderlich and Robert Chin).

So I added RCSwitch class to my project, connect graphic and it looks great, but! It does not work great. Check this out:

this code:

```
//@interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) RCSwitchOnOff *onSwitch;

//implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.onSwitch = [[RCSwitchOnOff alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 39.5, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 150, 80, 35)];
    [self.onSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//    self.defaultSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 39.5, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 150, 80, 35)];
//    [self.defaultSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

.
.
.
}

- (void)switchSwitched:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"switch touched!");
}
```

cause this in NSLog

```
2013-03-15 09:56:54.575 Secret-Project[1190:c07] switch touched!
2013-03-15 09:56:54.576 Secret-Project[1190:c07] switch touched!
```

For **one** user touch method switchSwitched fires two times!
And when I uncommnet defaultSwitch and comment onSwitch, the normal UISwitch start switchSwitched method only once.

What the heck? Is here someone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, 
RCSwitch.m have this method:

```
- (void)performSwitchToPercent:(float)toPercent
{
    endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:fabsf(percent - toPercent) * animationDuration];
    percent = toPercent;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}
```

Last line senda action and because of this method for switch is launching two times.

Comment: Hod did you solve it? I don't suppose that commenting the last line in the library is the solution, right?

Comment: Actually I commented last line but after all in final version I gived up on using RCSwitch so maybe there is another solution.
By the way: if you comment last line switch is still working properly.